# Apach в браузер выдаёт пустоту

Tags: ubuntu, apache

Выдохся, помогайте:
На VPS Ubuntu Server 22, Apache, php, msql, плюс в процессе установка joomla. На этапе установки php и mysql браузер на удалённом клиенте выдавал проверку по http://217.107.217.56 info.php, а, когда ставил джумлу, с соответствующими правками - всё прекратилось - Апач на info.php выдавал пустоту, на себя и на /joomla/ выдавал свою страничку. Теряюсь в догадках - прошу пованговать.

Я переустановил Апач - и теперь он вообще не выдаёт ни чего - тока на джумлу выдаёт свою страничку (думаю - из кеша). Изменил текст в оной страничке - но браузер этот текст не показал.

Comment: настройте виртуальные хосты. у вас дефолтная страница показывается их /var/www/html/

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-18-04-ru

Comment: Ну, пока, по инфе

Comment: не понял...о чем вы?

Comment: Ну, пока, по инфе - https://techexpert.tips/ru/joomla-ru/%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-joomla-%D0%BD%D0%B0-ubuntu-linux/ , у меня все запросы адресуются туда. В /etc/apache2/apache2.conf было <<Directory /var/www/html/>, я сейчас изменил на <Directory /var/www/html> - дробь удалил, и заработало info.php, но сам айпишник, и джумла, ничего не выдают. Буду дальше копать.

Comment: http://217.107.217.56/joomla/installation/index.php

Comment: Странно...
Спасибо. 
По инфе - должна отрабатывать ссылка http://217.107.217.56/joomla/ - а она выдаёт кешевую страничку апача.
https://217.107.217.56/ - не отрабатывает.
http://217.107.217.56/ - отрабатывает апачевую страничку с изменённым мной текстом.
То-есть - разница в S - как это понимать? Что настроить - чтоб S работало?
И не понятно - почему, при переинсталляции апача - приветственная страничка с моими изменениями не затёрлось установочной...

Собственно, топик-проблема решена, спасибо. В инфе не сказано - что нужно по указанному вами пути джумлу вызывать.